# Expo infoPlist showing default messages instead of custom

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm getting rejected by Apple because of default permission messages. I have changed my app.json file, but doesnt work in my app, still shows defaults. In my app I'm using expo-barcode-scanner, expo-image-picker and expo-calendar. My app.json looks like this:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "xx",
    "slug": "xx",
    "version": "3.1.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/xx.png",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "assets/fonts/*"
    ],
    "plugins": [
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "infoPlist": {
        "NSCameraUsageDescription": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access camera. This is necessary to be able to take a profile picture, and to read QR codes.",
        "NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access camera. This is necessary to be able to take a profile picture, and to read QR codes.",
        "NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access camera. This is necessary to be able to take a profile picture, and to read QR codes.",
        "NSMicrophoneUsageDescription": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your microphone",
        "NSCalendarsUsageDescription": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your calendar. This is necessary to be able to save events to your phone's calendar."
      },
      "bundleIdentifier": "xx",
      "buildNumber": "3.0.15"
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "versionCode": 6,
      "permissions": [
        "android.permission.CAMERA",
        "android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO",
        "android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR",
        "android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"

      ],
      "package": "xx"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "xx"
      }
    },
    "owner": "xx"
  }
}
```

Couldnt find issue similar to mine